# Converting and understanding values in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I've been studying solidity and I've been looking at similar projects already on mainnet ethereum via etherscan. I'm trying to understand what values were used for certain functions of a contract. When I look at it I see stuff like this

```
Function: someUintFunction1(uint256 maxTxAmount)

MethodID: 0xec28438a
[0]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a2a15d09519be00000

Function: someUintFunction2(uint256 _minimumTokensBeforeSwap)

MethodID: 0xf0f165af
[0]:  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b5e3af16b1880000
=

Function: someBoolFunction(bool _enabled)

MethodID: 0xc49b9a80
[0]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I guess 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 as a bool is false?

but how  can I decode 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a2a15d09519be00000 and 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b5e3af16b1880000 to a readable value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but how can I decode 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a2a15d09519be00000 and 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b5e3af16b1880000 to a readable value?

These are values of the `uint256` params, converted to hexadecimal, displayed using big endian (the largest value is left).

You can convert it to decimal manually, or here's an example using [web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/) JS library:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3();

const decimal = web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter('uint256', '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a2a15d09519be00000');
console.log(decimal); // prints 3000000000000000000000
```